# Make "Snap to Canvas Edges" the default?

Tags: gimp, snapping, configuration

Using GIMP 2.8.22 on Windows. More often than not, I like to have `View -> Snap to Canvas Edges` checked.  How can I make this the default?

The only thing I could find is a forum post from 2007 which suggests modifying the source code http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/26643-how-do-i-set-default-values-for-gimp/

Comment: info about gimprc settings file: https://www.gimp.org/man/gimprc.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that was easy.  I've been wanting this for a least a year.  I found this post on github:

https://gist.github.com/wrzlbrmft/53c39525cfa7a3e12f58

```
# ~/.gimp-*/gimprc
(default-snap-to-canvas yes)
```

That worked! I closed gimp, added above line to `C:\Users\username\.gimp-2.8\gimprc` file and restarted gimp

**Update for GIMP 2.10**

In Gimp 2.10 the above doesn't seem to work.  The location of snap settings has changed to:

```
# (default-view
#     (show-menubar yes)
#     (show-statusbar yes)
#     (show-rulers yes)
#     (show-scrollbars yes)
#     (show-selection yes)
#     (show-layer-boundary yes)
#     (show-guides yes)
#     (show-grid no)
#     (show-sample-points yes)
#     (snap-to-guides yes)
#     (snap-to-grid no)
#     (snap-to-canvas no)
#     (snap-to-path no)
#     (padding-mode default)
#     (padding-color (color-rgb 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000)))
```

(Note, you can see the possible settings in the system gimprc. In Windows this is located at `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\etc\gimp\2.0\gimprc`)

However despite adding the following to my user gimprc and restarting gimp the snapping didn't seem to apply.

```
(default-view
    (snap-to-canvas yes)
```

Then I realized the gimprc I was editing was under a gimp-2.8 folder (`C:\Users\username\.gimp-2.8\gimprc`). I do not seem to have a gimp-2.10 folder in my user directory.

In any case, however, there is now a setting for it in the GUI.  Go to the menu `Edit->Preferences` and the section `Image Windows->Snapping`.  Updating this setting sticks between restarts

[image]

Comment: You will remove it. It looks like a good idea, but you'll quickly find that having it permanently on is a pain. What you can do instead is assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Just yesterday, I read a tweet from someone who praised the decision to not have this as a default in GIMP :)

Comment: @xenoid will see how it goes :) I'll remember that if it doesn't work out

Comment: Btw, there is already a shortcut to enable/disable it: `Alt`-`Ctrl`-`E`

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher, Wow, I don't understand why isn't it the default. Can you link to the tweet?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei https://twitter.com/adamrepa/status/905835701173932032